# onJsAlert of android similar in ios

Tags: ios

- Below is my code of android which and i want same thing in
  ios(objective-c)

private class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

```
    //display alert message in Web View
    @Override
    public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                .setMessage(message).setCancelable(true).show();
        result.confirm();
        return true;
    }

    }
```

Comment: What is the question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://github.com/ryanmaxwell/UIAlertView-Blocks if not -  look for something like UIAlertView based on blocks

Comment: above is code of android which detect script and change it title,message, i want same thing in ios